# Filter search floors from database, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this search function for offices it can search office name but what I want is able to filter floors as well like you type in "1st Floor" it shows the offices that belong in that floor

[image]

[image]

Here's the code:

BuildingController.php

```
 public function show($id)  
    {

    $building = Building::find($id);

    $search = \Request::get('search');

   $offices = Office::where('building_id',  $id)->where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->orderBy('floor')->get();  
}
```

I tried using this kind of function `// $offices = Office::where('building_id',  $id)->where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->orWhere('floor','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->orderBy('floor')->get();` to be able to search for floor as well but it screwed up my programs like it shows all the offices in every building even the one that it doesn't belong to.

building.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>['building',$building->id],'role'=>'search']) !!}

                       <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." >
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</i>
           </button>
          </span>
            </div>
             {!! Form::close()!!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`where()` closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
$offices = Office::where('building_id', $id)
    ->where(function($q) use($search) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
          ->orWhere('floor', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    })
    ->orderBy('floor')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '{'     @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @Doe there was a redundant `)` near the `use()`. Updated.